# Why is BasicLuisDialog.cs not in dialog section of web app bot?

Tags: azure, bots, azure-bot-service

`BasicLuisDialog.cs` is not my web app bot under dialog section. I have created basic bot with C# language and give the luis app id key and host name in bot settings

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please describe your problem and expectation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your issue?